# Who are my Employer and Supervisor when I'm working a freelance job?

Tags: new-job, applications, employer, freelance

I'm filling out an application that requires my last three places of employment. Most recently I've been doing freelance tutoring for a family. I've been working with the parent to handle the logistics and payment, and only working with the student on the actual tutoring. What should I put in the Employer and Supervisor slots?

Comment: When in doubt, go with whoever pays your invoices. So in this case the parent.

Comment: Do you have a business licence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should I put in the Employer and Supervisor slots?

A freelancer is self-employed. Your supervisor is whoever supervises your work. That depends on the particular gig.

If the form permits, putting "Self-employed" usually communicates the situation well. If they are looking for references, the parents are the one who supervise your work. Ask them if they are willing to be references.

Answer (score 0):

None. As freelancer you do not have an employer and you do not have a supervisor (which is a role that is higher than you in the employment hierarchy). You are self-employed. Put that into the application. If you mention it at all - sorry, but "tutoring for a family"... unless you apply for a very beginner job (when this is absolutely fine) this has no place on a job application, unless hit was a full time thing. And then the little question would come up how this was legal (because in most jurisdictions freelance activity requires you to actually market yourself, which sort of would mean MULTIPLE families, not one).